# How to set up Airflow Send Email?

Tags: python, smtp, airflow

I followed online tutorial to set up Email SMTP server in airflow.cfg as below:

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp


[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
# Uncomment and set the user/pass settings if you want to use SMTP AUTH 
# smtp_user =                       
# smtp_password =  
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = myemail@gmail.com
```

And my DAG is as below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.email_operator import EmailOperator

def print_hello():
    return 'Hello world!'

default_args = {
        'owner': 'peter',
        'start_date':datetime(2018,8,11),
}

dag = DAG('hello_world', description='Simple tutorial DAG',
          schedule_interval='* * * * *',
          default_args = default_args, catchup=False)

dummy_operator = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3, dag=dag)

hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', python_callable=print_hello, dag=dag)

email = EmailOperator(
        task_id='send_email',
        to='to@gmail.com',
        subject='Airflow Alert',
        html_content=""" <h3>Email Test</h3> """,
        dag=dag
)

email >> dummy_operator >> hello_operator
```

I assumed the email operator will run after the other two operators and then send me an email.
But email was not sent to me.
I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Best

Comment: Did you get an error?

Comment: @mad_ No, I didn't get any error. But email was not sent to my email address. I have no idea how to make it happen.

Comment: Please add the output of your dag run in the question.

Comment: ***I assumed the email operator will run after the other two operators***. Actually, 't1 >> t2' in airflow context means that t2 will happen after t1

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Setting up SMTP Server for Airflow Email alerts using Gmail**:

Create an email id from which you want to send alerts about DAG failure or if you want to use **EmailOperator**. Edit `airflow.cfg` file to edit the smtp details for the mail server.

For demo you can use any gmail account.

Create a google App Password for your gmail account ([Instruction here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)). This is done so that you don't use your original password or 2 Factor authentication.

1. Visit your [App passwords](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) page. You may be asked to sign in to your Google Account.
2. Under "Your app passwords", click **Select app** and choose "Mail".
3. Click **Select device** and choose "Other (Custom name)" so that you can input "Airflow".
4. Select **Generate**.
5. Copy the generated App password (the 16 character code in the yellow bar), for example xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyy.
6. Select **Done**.

Once you are finished, you won’t see that App password code again. However, you will see a list of apps and devices (which you've created App passwords for) in your Google Account.

Edit `airflow.cfg` and edit the `[smtp]` section as shown below:

```
[smtp]
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
smtp_password = xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyy
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS
```

Edit the below parameters to the corresponding values:

`YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS` = Your Gmail address
`xxxxyyyyxxxxyyyy` = The App password generated above

Comment: this does seem to be working for many but is not working for me. I am not getting any emails, i have exact configuration.

Comment: do you know how to set this for a Google Group email instead of a personal Gmail account? I want to use Airflow to send emails from a Google Group email address

Comment: I have found some helpful documentation here if sending from Google G Suite and not Gmail https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: can you use your usual password instead of the `16_DIGIT_PASSWORD` if you dont want to use the app-password?

Comment: This worked for me! I used the 16 digit password generated by app passwords.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and i solved it by making sure i am doing a volume mount in my compose file

```
volumes:
  - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
  - ./config/airflow.cfg:/usr/local/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

Comment: I have no clue why this works, but it does. You saved my day. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this issue. I changed the airflow.cfg with correct setting, but it's still not working. Finally, I found out that I should restart the airflow scheduler to load the changes of airflow.cfg. After I restarted the scheduler, it worked fine.
The following two setting are both ok.

```
[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = True
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_user = youremail@gmail.com                      
smtp_password =  your password
smtp_port = 587
smtp_mail_from = youremail@gmail.com
```

---------or------------------

```
[smtp]
# If you want airflow to send emails on retries, failure, and you want to use
# the airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp function, you have to configure an
# smtp server here
smtp_host = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_starttls = False
smtp_ssl = True
smtp_user = youremail@gmail.com                      
smtp_password =  your password
smtp_port = 465
smtp_mail_from = youremail@gmail.com
```