# Success mail in Airflow

Tags: python, email, airflow

How can I get success mail in airflow after complete execution of a each dags.

This is what I have tried.
I am tring to get a success mail on completion of dags
Can anyone will help me out.
I have import all the files that are required.

```
i = datetime.now()

default_args = {
'owner': 'owner',
'depeneds_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(i.year, i.month, i.day-1),
'email': ['owner@gmail.com'],
'email_on_failure': True,
'email_on_retry': True,
'email_on_success': True,
'retries': 0,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10)
}

dag = DAG('update', default_args = default_args, 
schedule_interval="0 3 * * *")


t0 = PythonOperator(
task_id='clear',
python_callable=empty_tables,
email_on_failure=True,
email_on_success=True,
email=['owner@gmail.com'],
dag=dag
)

# Add tasks now 
t1 = BashOperator(
task_id='export',
bash_command=script,
dag=dag
)


t2 = PythonOperator(
task_id='load',
python_callable=load,
email_on_failure=True,
email_on_success=True,
email=['owner@gmail.com'],
dag=dag
)



t0 >> t1 >> t2
```

Comment: Please show the code you've written so far and any error messages, this will make it easier for people to help

Answer (score 4):

You need to configure SMTP server and add this to `airflow.cfg` file.

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51837049/5691525 to see how you can setup SMTP Server for Airflow Email alerts using Gmail.

Comment: Is there any reason against developing an "email_on_success" parameter for DAGs or just nobody has started to code it?

Answer (score 3):

While there exists 'email_on_failure' key to raise alerts in case of failed task, there isn't any key defined in airflow code as 'email_on_success'. Hence, in order to trigger an email alert on success, you would have to make use of 'on_success_callback'

Answer (score 1):

[sending emails using jinja templates in python](https://sites.google.com/site/mrxpalmeiras/python/send-email-using-jinja-template?fbclid=IwAR2rnllu2rb0PhbE7pc-BGOlhGoTZKp74t4H8NKZrmuwlNlBmrChI15Zd5U)
Here's the DAG and how to use **on_success_callback**

```py
def email_func():
    # https://sites.google.com/site/mrxpalmeiras/python/send-email-using-jinja-template?fbclid=IwAR2rnllu2rb0PhbE7pc-BGOlhGoTZKp74t4H8NKZrmuwlNlBmrChI15Zd5U
    # I'm referring to send_email from the above package/code
    send_email(to, subject)

def callable_func(context):
    to = "to@domain.com"
    subject = 'on success callback trial'
    html = "/path/to/html"
    email_func(to, subject, html)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 9, 15),
    'retries': 1,
    'email': ['your_email@your_domain.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'on_success_callback': callable_func,
}
```