# GCP command to retrieve an SMTP Password for airflow

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, smtp, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I've followed kaxil answer in [How to set up Airflow Send Email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829200/how-to-set-up-airflow-send-email) to setup airflow, however gcp doesn't allow to set:

```
smtp_password = 16_DIGIT_APP_PASSWORD
```

explicity inside cloud composer. I checked on google documentation https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/configure-email#smtp_password and found out that there is a way to set it by Using a command to retrieve an SMTP password.

- `smtp_password_cmd` does not appear as a key in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html?highlight=smtp_password_cmd#smtp-password but as an environment variable, therefore is it possibile to do as suggested by the google documentation and set `smtp   smtp_password_cmd   Specify a command that returns the SMTP password.` ?
- i'm absolutely clueless on how to create a command and what to pass as an argument in `Specify a command that returns the SMTP password`, if for example my smtp password is : `dummypassword1` could someone provide an example of such command and how to set it inside the config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an better way to do this than `smtp_passwd_cmd`:

- Use [Google Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets).
- [Configure Google Secrets Manager as the Airflow secrets backend](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-secret-manager)
- Add the SMTP password to the secrets manager.
- Override the Airflow configuration for `smtp_password_secret` to point to the secret you just created for this.

This is better explained here: https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-email#using_a_secret_stored_in_to_retrieve_an_smtp_password

This way everything is just configuration.

Using Google Cloud Secret Manager for this purpose falls in the free tier for the service (see [Secret Manager pricing](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/pricing))