# Command to retrieve SMTP Password by airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

How to retrieve SMTP password by airflow using **smtp_password_cmd** value?

I have added all the environment variables in composer environment which intern overrides airflow configuration.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n00HE.jpg (Refer this image)

Please give me a brief understanding of what command need to add in composer environment, so that it airflow uses this command to get the value of password?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681089/gcp-command-to-retrieve-an-smtp-password-for-airflow), it is better to use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview) for this purpose. To use a secret stored in Secret Manager to retrieve an SMTP password, you can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/configure-email#using_a_secret_stored_in_to_retrieve_an_smtp_password).

Posting this as a wikianswer for the benefit of the community as well.